# Open Stream API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, social-networking

I am wondering if there is a common mechanism for a third-party side to access to any social network data, and I found this [social-networks connect services](http://www.pintrestalk.com/ddata/2090.pdf). In this article, they describe 4 stages for a third party to connect to a social network.

1) **Identity Authentication:** the third-party application can use the authentication services provided by social network side (e.g., OAuth) to authenticate users.

2) **Authorization:** the social network provide the permission for the third-party side to access its own data. (normally, social networks again use OAuth to manage the access right)

3) **Streams:** let third-party sites publish to users' activity stream and vice versa. (e.g., **Facebook uses Open Stream API**)

4) **Applications:** let third-party sites develop rich social features within the application scope (e.g., the third-party sides can use Graph API, FQL to update Facebook information)

---

***My question is***

1) Is it true to apply to any social network throughout this above mechanism?

2) I've read the Open Stream API that Facebook launched 3 years ago, and when I open Facebook API documents, I don't see it anymore. Is it true that Facebook is no longer supporting this api. Or in the case I misunderstood, is it possible to consider FQL, Graph API the same as Open Stream API in Facebook? or they are different?

Answer (score 0):

Social Networking sites do not give direct access to their streaming data. For e.g facebook gives us public data access through it's Graph/Search API & FQL.

But for streaming data you may have to contact one of their authorized data re-sellers. They can give you one point access to all social networks you need.[Datasift](http://www.datasift.com) & [GNIP](http://gnip.com) are the two I remember on the top of my mind. I'm stuck at a similar point, you may also want to keep a track of [my SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21719434/facebook-graph-api-callbacks-real-time-api-public-feed-api) which is on similar lines.